# With which command should I open .raw.gz files?

Tags: unix, gzip

I have a bunch of .raw.gz files which are data files streamed from twitter with JSON interface. I am wondering which command should I use on my Mac OSX to open (unzip) these files? I have tried tar, unzip, gunzip, none of them worked for me.

Comment: But gunzip should give you the .raw file. Then, are you aware of what the .raw file is?

Comment: Agree with Xichen. Hence the `file` use.

Comment: This is what I get when I run gunzip hoktay@csreg193>gunzip twitter_20091006.raw.gz

gunzip: twitter_20091006.raw.gz: not in gzip format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the `file` command, if that is available on MacOSX, to check the file type. Anyway, I think you should do that after gunziping the x.raw.gz file (which normally gives you a x.raw file). Normally, you should obtain raw json text file after doing gunzip.

Comment: This is what I get when I rurn the file command:                   file twitter_20091006.raw.gz
twitter_20091006.raw.gz: data

Comment: Ouch… Did you try to open the file in text mode and see if there is a human readable text? Could you share how did you get those file? It may help.

Comment: This is the information about how the files are obtained.Files contain singular larger continuous ingestions. Files are in JSON format.
curlStream.bat was used with a program called cURL to download the Twitter stream.
The Twitter API is located at http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation.  Most JSON fields are defined at http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Return-Values.  curlStream.bat invokes the Twitter Streaming API, with documentation at http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Streaming-API-Documentation.

Comment: And I tried to open, but it is not human readable text unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, I can't test since I don't want to register myself on devtwitter. Anyway, since curl should by default redirect your data on the standard console output my advice is that you could try elementary curl call on the Twitter API when tweaking some curl parameters (see `curl -h`).